# gradle build with AAR failed with No resource found error

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, aapt

I have two modules in the project.

- app - that's my app module
- app-base - that's android library module my app uses.

When I build with build tool 21 and gradle android plugin 1.1.1
with following dependency, it will fail.

```
compile 'com.company.android:app-base:1.0.0@aar'
```

I deployed app-base aar to company sonatype Nexus by following command.

```
gradle uploadArchives
```

The error messages follows:

```
:app:processCustomAppDebugResources
 Position 34:21-35 : No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'actionBarStyle'.
 Position 34:21-35 : No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'actionBarStyle'.
 Position 37:29-51 : No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'windowActionBarOverlay'.
 Position 29:21-36 : No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'windowActionBar'.
 Position 1 : Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
 Position 1 : Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.Solid'.
 Position 19:21-44 : No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'actionBarItemBackground'.
 Position 7:21-31 : No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'background'.
 Position 17:21-45 : No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'selectableItemBackground'.
 Position 14:32-46 : No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'titleTextStyle'.
 Position 7:21-31 : No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'background'.
 Position 1 : Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
 Position 1 : Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.

:app:processCustomAppDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processCustomAppDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/service/android/default/sdk/build-tools/21.0.0/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

To build successfully this, I only need to remove @aar on same dependency.

```
compile 'com.company.android:app-base:1.0.0'
```

Could someone explain why this happens? What is difference using AAR dependency or not using it?

Comment: I have this problem also?when use remote aar will be error, if I down load this aar as local file it is work well.do you resolve it?

Comment: @Carl, I am not sure what your problem is, but in my case I do remove "@aar" on dependency configuration. "@aar" will not propagate dependencies on that AAR module has. I wonder how you define your AAR file dependency on your app module.

Comment: I am changing project from`sub-modlue` to dependence `aar` which in our company maven server.so there happen this problem.

Comment: @Carl, If you define `compile 'com.yourcompany.android:your-applib-aar:1.0.0'`, then it throws error?

Comment: yes ,now I have resoled this problem.I just clean the `.m\repository\myuseAAR` in my PC，because the first time build  use the  arr has a error,after that the build will use local repository.

Answer (score 0):

Those parameters are from Android Support Library. Have you already included the Android Support Library in your dependency list?

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
```

Comment: I feel like grabbing something, it is declared in app-base not app module. so @AAR dependency make not propagate the dependencies from app-base module?

Comment: Yup. app module propagates the dependencies from app-base but does not on the contrary. In your case, you are going to compile app-base module as an aar file so only app-base module is compiled. You have to declare dependencies in app-base module as well.